# react native alt flux cannot bind action to store

Tags: javascript, react-native, flux

I have a LoginActions.js files that looks like this :

```
'use strict';

import alt from '../alt';
import LoginUtils from '../utils/login';

class LoginActions {

  loginSuccess(me) {
    return me;
  }

  loginFailed(err) {
    return err;
  }

  loginCancelled() {
    return function (dispatch) {
      dispatch()
    }
  }

  logout() {
    return function (dispatch) {
      dispatch()
    }
  }

  login() {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch()
      LoginUtils.facebook((err, me) => {
        if (err === 'cancelled') {
          return this.loginCancelled();
        }
        if (err) {
          return this.loginFailed(err);
        }
        this.loginSuccess(me);
      });
    }
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(LoginActions);
```

And a Store that looks like this :

```
'use strict';

import alt from '../alt';
import _ from 'lodash';

import LoginActions from '../actions/LoginActions';
// import MeActions from '../actions/MeActions';
import CachedStore from './CachedStore';

class MeStore extends CachedStore {

  constructor () {
    super();

    this.me = {};

    this.bindListeners({
      handleLoginSuccess: LoginActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      handleLoginFailed: LoginActions.LOGIN_FAILED,
      handleLogout: LoginActions.LOGOUT,
      handleLogin: LoginActions.LOGIN,
      handleLoginCancelled: LoginActions.LOGIN_CANCELLED
    });
  }

... // all handlers are defined here
```

Yet, I don't understand why I have the error below...
I followed the steps explained here : https://github.com/goatslacker/alt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `handleLoginSuccess: LoginActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS,`
when your function name for login success in Actions is loginSuccess ?

try  `handleLoginSuccess: LoginActions.loginSuccess`

Comment: I tried it too and it doesn't work. I did it with the LOGIN_SUCCESS syntax in another app and it worked fine, I d'ont get it why it doesn't work here. But the error seems to be in the LoginActions import. LoginActions seems to be undefined from what I understand.

Comment: my alt.js file look like `import Alt from 'alt';
export default new Alt();` and instead   
`export default alt.createActions(LoginActions);` I'm using `module.exports.LoginActions = alt.createActions(LoginActions);` and in store I'm imporing actions this way `import {LoginActions} from '../actions/loginactions';` I also had problems without {} around LoginActions

Comment: I've tried `module.exports.LoginActions = alt.createActions(LoginActions);` with `import {LoginActions} from '../actions/loginactions';` but I get the same error. Could it be related to babel compiler ? I've had issues with it previously, maybe I missed integrating a preset or plugin...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I got it to work by deleting the LoginActions.js file and starting a new one exactly the same from scratch... Can't explain why it didn't work though.